# Overfull hbox caused by paragraph consisting of a single line

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, paragraphs, overfull

I have a document using A4 paper and relatively smaller margins than default (3cm), so the line width is quite large. There are some paragraphs that consist of a single line, for which I'm getting an overfull hbox warning, even though the line does not extend beyond the right margin.

Why is the warning generated if the line does not extend beyond the right margin? Is there some setting for the maximum number of characters on a single line that I have to adapt if I'm using such a large line width?

Is there a way to suppress warnings in these situations automatically (not dealing with them on a case-by-case basis), while keeping the warnings for overfull hbox where the right margin *is* protruded? Or is that a bad idea?

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

For each forrrrm, give the conjugation, PGN (as applicable), and translation (see section 1.8).

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> parfill With package option parfill, the package also adjusts
> \parfillskip to impose a minimum space at the end of the last line of
> a paragraph. If speciﬁed without a value then 30pt are assumed, if a
> value is given that forms the minimum.

TeX has limits on how much inter-word spaces can stretch or shrink, and the line can not be broken while leaving 30pt  at the end.

If you use `\sloppy` there is more flexibility, or you can allow  smaller end of paragraph space .

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

For each forrrrm, give the conjugation, PGN (as applicable), and translation (see section 1.8).


\sloppy
For each forrrrm, give the conjugation, PGN (as applicable), and translation (see section 1.8).

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill=30pt minus 5pt]{parskip}

\begin{document}

For each forrrrm, give the conjugation, PGN (as applicable), and translation (see section 1.8).


\end{document}
```

Comment: I never thought it could be due to `parfill`; I thought I just couldn't find a MWE sentence without it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The option `parfill` is defined by

```
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=parskip,prefix=parskip@}
...
\DeclareStringOption[0pt]{parfill}[30pt]
```

which means that `\parskip@parfill` is initially defined as `0pt`, but if the option is specified, the definition will change to `30pt` (or to the supplied value if one says `parfill=20pt`, for instance).

Later the package does

```
\setlength\parfillskip\parskip@parfill
\advance\parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax
```

so with your setting you end up with the same as

```
\setlength{\parfillskip}{30pt plus 1fil}
```

which means that at the end of *any* paragraph you get at least 30pt of blank space. Of course, a one-line paragraph whose text extends to less than 30pt from the right margin will be overfull. For longer paragraphs (three or more lines), there's usually room for shrinking or stretching the interword spacing to fit the requirement.

The idea of `parfill` is to not end paragraphs too near the right margin. Whether this is a good idea, it's the typesetter to decide based on the text they're given.

This might be good if you use *zero* `\parskip` and no paragraph indentation, but with nonzero `\parskip` its usefulness is very dubious. *Maybe* it could help when a paragraph ends very close to the right margin *and* at the bottom of a page, because in this case the vertical space between paragraphs disappears in the page break. What are the chances of this happening? Perhaps one or two page breaks on 100 pages. The revision phase will catch them and fix by adding some unremovable space at the end of the offending paragraph (say `\hspace*{30pt}`).

Remove the option.

Final advice, but it's personal opinion. Don't use nonzero `\parskip`, but the centuries old traditional indentation: if you have short paragraphs, then `parskip` will produce output even more awful than it's when paragraphs are long.

Comment: Thanks for walking me through the typographical considerations, that's very helpful.